# Атрибут `resource` для тега `td`

Tags: html, css

Встретил таблицу, в которой одна из ячеек имеет аттрибут `resource`:

```
<td resource="Файл:Мост.jpg">...</td>
```

Что означает этот атрибут `resource`?

Comment: Аттрибут можно назвать, как вам угодно, а потом использовать в JS. Это просто ещё один инструмент для манипуляции HTML разметкой.

Comment: но для стандарта лучше использовать аттрибуты с приставкой data, получится data-resourse=".."

Comment: Вот-вот, я думал, что пользовательские атрибуты должны начинаться с префикса `data-`. А тут не начинается, вот и удивился

Comment: `Вот-вот, я думал, что пользовательские атрибуты должны начинаться с префикса data-` - **могут**, но НЕ должны